# When I click to reserve, I can't save the reservation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have received the value from the search page and shown in the booking page but also want to record that value as room, details, booking date, booking end and total price of the booking. but cannot save the value

`view.py`

```
def booking_cat_hotel(request, room_number, check_in_date, check_out_date):
    one_room = Room.objects.get(room_number=room_number)
    num_days = (datetime.strptime(check_out_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - datetime.strptime(check_in_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()).days
    total_price = num_days * one_room.price

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            booking = form.save(commit=False)
            booking.room = one_room
            booking.start_date = datetime.strptime(check_in_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            booking.end_date = datetime.strptime(check_out_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            booking.total_price = total_price
            booking.save()
            return redirect('completed', booking_id=booking.id)
    else:
        form = BookingForm(initial={
            'room': one_room,
            'room_number': one_room.room_number,
            'start_date': check_in_date,
            'end_date': check_out_date,
        })

    context = {
        "one_room": one_room,
        "check_in_date": check_in_date,
        "check_out_date": check_out_date,
        "form": form,
        "total_price": total_price,
    }

    return render(request, 'cat_hotel/cat_hotel.html', context=context)
```

`html`

```
<form action="{% url 'booking_cat_hotel' room_number=one_room.room_number check_in_date=check_in_date check_out_date=check_out_date %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card p-4 mt-5">
            <div class="row g-3">
                <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                    <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                        <h4>Room {{ one_room.room_number }}</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">{{ one_room.description }}</span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="room_number" value="{{ one_room.room_number }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="room_description" value="{{ one_room.description }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 ml-3">
                    <h5>Check-in Date</h5>
                    <p class="text-primary">{{ check_in_date }}</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="check_in_date" value="{{ check_in_date }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    <h5>Check-out Date</h5>
                    <p class="text-primary">{{ check_out_date }}</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="check_out_date" value="{{ check_out_date }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 ml-3">
                    <input type="text" name="cat_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Cat Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-10 ml-3">
                    <input type="text" name="phone_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 mb-4 mt-4 ml-3">
                    <h5>Total Price: {{ total_price }} baht</h5>
                    <input type="hidden" name="total_price" value="{{ total_price }}">
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 mt-4 ml-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase" href="{% url 'search_available_rooms' %}">Cancel</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase">Confirm Booking <i class="fa fa-plane ms-3"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`forms.py`

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'}), label='วันที่เข้าฝาก')
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'}), label='ถึงวันที่')

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['room', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'cat_name', 'phone_number']
```

`model`

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=False)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    confirm_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    staying_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
```

I want  reservations to be recorded.